# simple view and complex view

Tags: sql, function, view, oracle11g

I have a question about simple view vs complex view of SQL.

Man said 'A Simple view does not contain functions but Complex views contain functions'.

But how about this one?

```
Create or Replace View view_sal
as
select deptno, sum(sal) as "sum", avg(sal) as "avg"
from emp
group by deptno;
```

It is a simple view. but contains function.

Anyone can explain to me plz?

I am using Oracle 11g.

Answer (score 1):

You example is a complex view due to existence of grouping. The division of definitions used for defining a possibility to perform a DML:

> One can perform DML operations directly against simple views.

From [orafaq.com](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/View)

Answer (score 1):

** A simple view is a view that allows only a view from one table, else the complex view is a view that allows a view from more than one table.**

Answer (score 0):

Simple view vs complex view? There is no such distinction as far as I am aware. Views are more or less complex. Same as select statements, btw.

Who forces you to make such distinction? Is it possible that this refers to a practice inside your company? Someone defining rules on what views are allowed in your company, maybe?

Try to find out who demands the distinction, then ask them for the rules and show them your query.